# How to restrict Old vs. Young: in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to simulate the following situation. Young and old agents.
The old have few social contacts, slower and at the same time have a greater chance of dying.
Young people have more contacts .
Which group should be vaccinated first ?
I created two groups, assigned an infection algorithm, and assigned a social distance. But at the same time I do not see the relationship, the agents behave identically, where is the error?

I'm a beginner and  don't want to complicate the model. please don't answer difficult I'm just learning

my code

```
;;breed [humans human]
;;humans-own [   old   young ]


breed [young p-young]
breed [old p-old]

young-own [
  days-after-infected
  days-of-sick


]
old-own [
  days-after-infected
  days-of-sick ]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-old
  setup-young
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end


to setup-old
 create-old population-old
 [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set color 4
  set shape "person"
  ]

end

to setup-young
  create-young population-young
 [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "person"
  set color 96
  ]

end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor 61]
end


 ;:ask old [random 360]
 ;;ask young [forward 1]


 to go
  
  move-old
  move-young
  transmission-old
  transmission-young
  incubation
  sickness
  tick

end

to move-old
  ask old [
    right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
end

to move-young
ask young  [
    right random 360
    forward 3   
  ]
end

to add-carrier
  ask one-of young
  [set color orange]

end

to transmission-old
  ask young with [color = orange]
  [let susceptible-person one-of old in-radius 3 with [color = 4]
  if susceptible-person != nobody
    [ask susceptible-person
      [if random 100 < transmission_rate
        [set color orange]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end



to transmission-young
  ask young with [color = orange]
  [let susceptible-person one-of young in-radius 2 with [color = 96]
  if susceptible-person != nobody
    [ask susceptible-person
      [if random 100 < transmission_rate
        [set color orange]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end

to incubation
  ask old with [color = orange]
  [ ifelse days-after-infected < incubation_period 
    [set days-after-infected days-after-infected + 1]       
    [set color red]
  ]
  ask young with [color = orange]
  [ ifelse days-after-infected < incubation_period 
    [set days-after-infected days-after-infected + 1]       
    [set color red ]
    
  ]
  
end

to sickness
  ask old with [ color = red ]
  [ifelse days-of-sick < 14 
    [set days-of-sick days-of-sick + 1]
    [ifelse random 100 < mortality 
      [die]
      [ set color blue ]
    ]
  ]
      
   ask young with [ color = red ]
  [ifelse days-of-sick < 14 
    [set days-of-sick days-of-sick + 1]
    [ifelse random 100 < mortality 
      [die]
      [ set color blue ]
    ]
  ]
end

I am trying to infect some agents from others, while I am not interested in the incubation period and trying to link age (less movement and less contact) with morbidity.
But I see that the result is not presentable, there is no dependence on age and morbidity.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transmission-old` is your problem. You copypasted from `transmission-young` but forgot to replace `ask young` with `ask old`

```
to transmission-old
  ask old with [color = orange]
  [let susceptible-person one-of old in-radius 3 with [color = 4]
  if susceptible-person != nobody
    [ask susceptible-person
      [if random 100 < transmission_rate
        [set color orange]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: yes, this is a clear mistake. But it doesn't save the model. my task is to check who is  infected  faster depending on age. I have set a different speed for agents, but it is still not enough, because I do not take into account social contacts. the young have a lot of them, the old have little, how to link it...no ideas

Comment: Well, in the current system you could make either of the two groups immune and see how that affect the time it takes for the entire other group to get infectes

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting for a week, I changed the concept, I think it's easier. How to describe the last block. If there is one infectious neighbor, he will transmit his infection with faithfulness....

```
breed [olds humanA]
breed [youngs humanB]

globals
[
humans
]

to setup
clear-all
create-olds humans_number * shareA
[
set color  64
set xcor random-xcor
set ycor random-ycor
set shape "person"
]
create-youngs humans_number * (1 - shareA)
[
set color  45
set xcor random-xcor
set ycor random-ycor
set shape "person"
]
set humans (turtle-set olds youngs)

ask olds
[

create-links-with (up-to-n-of (links_number_old * homophily_old) (other olds))
create-links-with (up-to-n-of (links_number_old * ( 1 - homophily_old)) (other 
humans))
    ]
ask youngs
[
create-links-with (up-to-n-of (links_number_young * homophily_young) (other 
youngs))
create-links-with (up-to-n-of (links_number_young * ( 1 - homophily_young)) 
(other humans))


ask patches
[

]


ask n-of 1 humans
[
set infected 1
set color red
]
reset-ticks

end

*to go
ask humans
[
if any? link-neighbors != red ]
[
set humans ......*
```

end

Comment: Since this is an update to the question, you should edit the question with this code instead of writing it down as an answer in order to keep with the structure of stackoverflow